# Add a prefix to values when using a yii\db\Query

Tags: yii2

Is there a way to add a prefix to values when using a DB query to get the data from a database? I have used a var as example to show you how I want it to be.

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())->select(['name' , 'product_image."$prefix"' ])->from('products');
```

Lets say that I want to add after every image path a prefix like `_250x250`, so the final output will be `pathToImage_250x250` or `uploads/pathToImage_250x250`.

Comment: Your example is not clear. What result should return this example query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`yii\db\Expression`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression) to create more advanced selects. For example for MySQL you may use [`CONCAT()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp) function for this:

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select([
        'name',
        'product_image' => \yii\db\Expression('CONCAT(product_image, :suffix)', [
            ':suffix' => '_250x250',
        ]),
    ])
    ->from('products');
```

Comment: Is there also a way to add values from the query as a prefix/suffix like :suffix => 'name'?

Comment: Just use column names, same as `product_image` was used in `CONCAT()`.